# OpenGL - Low FPS on simple 3d game

Tags: c++, opengl

I am developping a 3d game, but already at one of the first tests, with really few calculations I get around 3 or 4 fps.
The following is my entire code: http://pastebin.com/j2DWPS6Z
This is the Terrain.cpp file I used in the main code: http://pastebin.com/d1gnE5KH

Looking to the code I use for drawing, I am drawing only 400 polygons. As far as I know that's not supposed to drop the fps to around 3 to 4 fps.

The computer I am using is HP Elitebook 8570w, with 8GB ram and an Intel core i7, so that's not the problem.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong to cause the fps to be this low?

Comment: You might end up using a software rasterizer. Check the `GL_VENDER`, `GL_RENDERER` and `GL_VERSION` strings to see waht you actually got. Apart from that, using immediate mode is the slowest way for drawing (but even that should not be _that_ slow). And, virtually every single one of the GL functions you are using is deprecated.

Comment: Just btw do not use pastebin links here, better put your code in the question. SO questions should be self-contained - links break, SO questions don't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that the problem could be the call to `glFlush()` from the *inner loop* of `drawTerrain()`. You do not usually need to call this function, least of all from the inner loop. Try just removing it.

Comment: Removing the glFlush() indeed did the job. Thanks a lot